# Failed to upload a file to web service

Tags: java, android, web-services, apache

I have a web service that get a audio and do some operation on it and finally returns a string ,this web service have a web page like this

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="file" name="FileUpload3" id="FileUpload3" style="width:325px;" />
<input type="submit" name="Button6" value="Upload File" id="Button6" />   
<span id="Label1"></span>

</form>
```

when file choose for uploadfile3 and press upload file a same page should be reload and then show the string in span lable, I want to connect this web service by android so I tried below code to connect and upload file, the server response 200 code but no file uploads to server and no string shows, it seems that server press upload file without choosing file, what can I do? help please.

```
public void upLoad2Server() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://11.12.13.174/file_transfer_sample/ClientWebSite/Default.aspx");

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/test.wav");
    ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "audio/wav"); 
    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    reqEntity.addPart("FileUpload3", cbFile);
    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);  
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    Log.i("status", String.valueOf(response.getStatusLine()));
}
```

Comment: An easy way would be to use library like http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

Comment: This is not about web-services you are talking about! it's about filling a user form by a robot and send some data. I suggest you just contact the target system, and get a real web service. it may be illegal if you are doing right now, or simply if system just have a simple ui changes you will be no longer able to catch the span data. and after you get the data you need to parse the data(response-body).

Answer (score 0):

Check this code to upload file from Android to Web Server

```
public class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Object, String, Object>
{
URL connectURL;
String params;
String responseString;
String fileName;
byte[] dataToServer;
FileInputStream fileInputStream;
private int serverResponseCode;

private String serverResponseMessage;

private static final String TAG = "Uploader";


public void setUrlAndFile(String urlString, File fileName)
{
    Log.d(TAG,"StartUploader");

    try
    {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        connectURL = new URL(urlString);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.getStackTrace();
        publishProgress(e.toString());

    }
    this.fileName = fileName.getAbsolutePath()+".txt";

}

synchronized void doUpload()
{
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    Log.d(TAG,"lv1");

    try
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"doUpload");
        publishProgress("Uploading...");

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)connectURL.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection","Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
        DataOutputStream dos  = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"Uploaded\";filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        Log.d(TAG,"LvA");
        Log.d(TAG,twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd + ";Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"Uploaded\";filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

        int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

        int maxBufferSize = 1024;
        int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0, bufferSize);
        Log.d(TAG,"LvB");
        while(bytesRead > 0)
        {

            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        fileInputStream.close();
       dos.flush();

        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        int ch;
        Log.d(TAG,"LvC");
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
        while((ch=is.read()) != -1)
        {
            buff.append((char)ch);
        }
       // publishProgress(buff.toString());
        dos.close();


     // Responses from the server (code and message)
        serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
       // Log.d(TAG,"Buffer "+buff.toString());

        Log.d(TAG,"Server Response "+serverResponseMessage);
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.getStackTrace();
       publishProgress(e.toString());
    }
}

@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) 
{
    Log.d(TAG,"lv1a");
    doUpload();
    Log.d(TAG,"Uploading Completed! Path: "+connectURL);

    return null;
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress)
{
    //this.info.setText(progress[0]);
    Log.d("Progress", progress[0]);
}


}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check this code.It's upload a file to .NET httphandler server. It uses SSL self-signed security, but it's an example how to use methods, and multipart entity. It works for me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
         File f = new File(
                "c:\\eula.1028.txt");

         System.out.println("LENGTH " + f.length());        
         PostMethod method = new PostMethod("/Handler");            
         FilePart filePart = new FilePart("file",f);
         filePart.setContentType("application/pdf");
         Part[] parts = {filePart};
         MultipartRequestEntity request = new
         MultipartRequestEntity(parts, method.getParams());
         method.setRequestEntity(request);

        Protocol easyhttps = new Protocol("https",
                new EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory(), 2000);
        org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient client = new org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient();
        client.getHostConfiguration().setHost("localhost", 2000, easyhttps);

        client.executeMethod(method);
        String s = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
        System.out.println(s);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```